# Robotframework AWS assume role

Tags: robotframework

I am using RF RPA[AWS] library for Test automation, curently we move to S3 bucket which need a certain Role Setting to have an access to S3 bucket…
Are there any possibility to switch to a certain AWS ROLE after using [Init S3 Client] KW?
If not how can I map the needed AWS ROLE durring S3 Client initiallisation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's not possible with RPA[AWS]. I have written own RF library for that using boto3

This would work for getting Boto S3 Client and assuming role for that

```
def get_client(self):
    """
    Get client to AWS service and assume the role to that service.

    """
    
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="Test Profile")
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.assume_role(RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/TestRole", RoleSessionName="Test Session")
    session = Session(aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                      aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                      aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
                      region_name="your-region")
    return session.client(service)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that exactly what i tought before

Comment: Hi Dureq, Can you share the code snippet? If possible, it would be helpful.